# Limit execution time of Dynamic SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm using `EXECUTE sp_executesql @Command` to execute a dynamically built piece of code.

Is there any mechanism that would allow me to limit the execution time to a pre-defined number of seconds?

Comment: You can only handle this through the client via a timeout, and that will affect the session, not just the statement.

Comment: Thanis @EzLo, that is a possibility I already considered but, unfortunately, does not match my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Setting a per-query timeout is typically something you'd do in whatever code is going to invoke the query, not within the query itself. For instance, in .NET you can set [SqlCommand::CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx).

The closest thing I know of in T-SQL is [SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-query-governor-cost-limit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), and that doesn't quite do what you're asking; rather than terminating a query after X seconds, this setting will disallow a query from running in the first place if SQL Server *estimates* its execution time at greater than X seconds.

Comment: Thank you Joe for this post. Yes, the `SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT` and termination of the connection (from the client) were options I already checked and, much as you mentioned, they do not meet my needs. Still, your answer, though not solving my problem, deserve an up-vote.